# Changes to html /css not syncing to browser on Blazor application on mac

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, blazor-server-side

When I start a new Blazor server application, changes to HTML and CSS are not showing up unless I close the build and start a new build.
Im using VS for mac 2019, VS for mac 2022 (preview), and `Jetbrains` Rider. All are being run on a new M1 Mac book. All are having the same issue.

I can confirm I'm not having this problem when running an MVC application.

Tried running with both .net 5 and .net 6

Adding following to my `Startup.cs` file from other suggestions:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Comment: Just to eliminate this from the list, did you check the "Disable cache" option from your browser devtools? Since the MVC app is working fine, i guess you already have this option cheked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the project using `IISExpress` to see html changes to `.razor` files. Changes to `.cshtml` files can be seen on browser refresh without running `IISExpress` though.